# "NoMethodError: undefined method `object' for #<Tenant:blahblah>" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

Hello I am having an error of "NoMethodError: undefined method `information_requisition' for #" I cant seem to relate this model to my user. My code for information_requisition model is:

```
class InformationRequisition
  include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :admin
    has_many :reports
```

And my user model is:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  has_one :report,
  has_many :information_requisitions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :admin
  has_one :bill, dependent: :destroy
```

And I keep getting the error when I try and display a create form in a partial on a dashboard. Here is where the error shows on my dashboard controller:

class Tenants::DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_tenant!

```
  def show
    @dashboard = current_user
    @bill = current_user.bill || current_user.build_bill
    @information_requisition = current_user.information_requisition || current_user.build_information_requisition
  end
```

My information_requisition seems to not relate to the user. It keeps giving me the "NoMethodError: undefined method `information_requisition' for #" error. Any idea what I have wrong?

Comment: did you forget an 's'? current_user.information_requisition => current_user.information_requisitions

Comment: Hold on let me check I know it was not that simple!

Comment: Yep! You got it Thanks I don't know how I did'nt see that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `current_user` only has access to `information_requisitions` (plural) because it is a `has_many` association.

If `@information_requisition` is singular you have add a `.first` after the plural to get the first one. But my guess is that you really want to use `first_or_initialize`:

```
def show
    @dashboard = current_user
    @bill = current_user.bill || current_user.build_bill
    @information_requisition = current_user.information_requisitions.first_or_initialize
end
```

Comment: what if that user has more than one information_requisition wouldnt first just show the first one vs. if there are many? The reason is ask is because next to the partial that adds a information_requisition, I have a partial that should be an index showing all the information_requisitions that user has

Comment: Of course a user can have more than one information_requisition. Your code says 'has_many :information_requisitions' in the User model. has_many does mean has many. Please accept this answer and create a new question for the partial part.

Comment: That got it thanks. I will post a question about the index next if I don't figure it out.